# How ZFS deals with bad sectors?

Tags: zfs, badblocks

I have a disk with a couple of bad sectors. I've used `badblocks` to check which sectors were faulty. `dd` could not write zeroes to them and `smartctl -t long /dev/sdx` has failed.

I know that you can indicate which are the bad sectors to a filesystem with `mkfs.ext4 -l badsectors.txt /dev/sdx` but I was planning on using ZFS.

I would like to know:

1. Is there a similar way to inform ZFS about the bad sectors?
2. if not, will ZFS be aware of them?
3. will ZFS write to these sectors wihtout realizing that they are bad?

Thank you

Comment: You may wish to read [this](https://www.truenas.com/community/threads/shouldnt-zfs-freenas-deal-with-bad-sectors-for-me.56055/), with the third comment also containing a valuable link besides the information in it.